# android listview: how to change background color of specific cells (by index)?

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello and thanks in advance,

Is there a way to changed the background color of specific cells ?  Namely by index number ? I am attempting to modify this tutorial code below by adding an - if(position==3).  Not sure what I'm doing wrong or if it's even allowed.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList < ItemDetails > results) {
    itemDetailsrrayList = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
        //  holder.txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ////////////////////////////  TEST CODE - Header cells ////////////////


      if(position == 2){
      convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.background_light);
  }

    if (position == 3) {
         convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.background_light);
    }
    if (position == 14) {
         convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.background_light);
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////


    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
    // holder.txt_itemPrice.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there's not setBackground() in [BaseAdapater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) (if that's what you inherit from). If setBackground() is a method created by you, I don't understand how you're able to set the color of a specific view if you don't pass it as an argument. Don't you want to call convertView.[setBackgroundColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) instead?

Answer (score 0):

For any other beginners out there adding this snippet to getView() is what worked for me. Hope it helps someone.

```
 if(position == 0 || position == 7 || position == 9 || position == 15 ){


      convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
  }
  else
  {
      convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
  }
```